# Not able to add active class that matches current open page to list item of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem while adding the active class to the currently open page. I tried other solutions available on StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me. I think it is because I have ~/ in my link href element. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var current = location.pathname;
               $('#indexmenu li a').each(function () {
                   var $this = $(this);
                   if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
                       $this.addClass('active')
                   }
               })         
            })
    </script>


<div class="navbar-collapse collapse mancolor" id="adminmenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mancolor" id="indexmenu">
    <li><a href="~/Default.aspx" class="active" runat="server">
       <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i></span>
       <span>Main Screen</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="NewWorkShopVisit.aspx"  runat="server">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
        <span>New Workshop Visit</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Index.aspx" runat="server">
       <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></span>
       <span>Workshop Control Panel</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Employees.aspx" runat="server">
        <span><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></span>
        <span>Employees</span>
       </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check if the first character is a `~` and if it is, return the string without it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('#indexmenu li a').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var href = $this.attr('href');
        if (href.charAt(0) === '~') href = href.substr(1);
        if (href.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
            $this.addClass('active')
        }
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = '/Default.aspx'
  $('#indexmenu li a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.attr('href');
    if (href.charAt(0) === '~') href = href.substr(1);
    if (href.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
      $this.addClass('active')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse mancolor" id="adminmenu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mancolor" id="indexmenu">
    <li>
      <a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i></span>
        <span>Main Screen</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="NewWorkShopVisit.aspx" runat="server">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
        <span>New Workshop Visit</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Index.aspx" runat="server">
        <span><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></span>
        <span>Workshop Control Panel</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Employees.aspx" runat="server">
        <span><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></span>
        <span>Employees</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```